# Clever cite command

Tags: biblatex, citing, cleveref, multiple-citations

`cleveref`'s `\cref` command is great for automatically adding prefixes like fig(s)., section(s), eq(s). etc. to cross-references. Unfortunately, it doesn't (natively) offer this functionality for citations?

What I'm looking for is a command `\ccite` that behaves as follows:

- `\ccite{ref1}` - "**ref.**~[1]"
- `\ccite{ref1,ref5,ref11}` - "**refs.**~[1,5,11]"

Can `biblatex` be used to implement this? Or can `cleveref` be extended to support citations? If not, is there another package that offers this functionality which is compatible with both `biblatex` and `cleveref`? Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Early on, Herrmann showed in ref.~\cite{herrmann} that grass is green.

A collaborative research effort was later able to demonstrate in  refs.~\cite{bertram,doody,gillies,glashow} that the sky is blue.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: natbib also provide this feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the `\cite` command or create a new command that automatically adds "ref." or "refs.":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\NewBibliographyString{refname}
\NewBibliographyString{refsname}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  refname = {ref\adddot},
  refsname = {refs\adddot}
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {%
  \ifnum\thecitetotal=1
    \bibstring{refname}%
  \else%
    \bibstring{refsname}%
  \fi%
  \addspace\bibopenbracket%
  \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \bibclosebracket}

\renewrobustcmd*{\Cite}{\bibsentence\cite}


\begin{document}

In sentence \cite{herrmann}.

In sentence \cite{bertram,doody,gillies,glashow}.

\Cite{herrmann} at start of sentence.

\Cite{bertram,doody,gillies,glashow} at start of sentence.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1) Just one tiny thing: I'd use `refname = {ref\adddot},` instead of `refname = {ref.},`. That tells `biblatex` that the dot is an abbreviation dot and not a full stop.

Comment: I only want to change some citations to include the prefix. Most should remain as they are (which is why I suggested a new custom cite command). I like the fine-grain control `cleveref` offers with `\cref` and `\labelcref` and was hoping for the same with citations.

Comment: @Casimir It's entirely up to you how you call this cite command, for example `\DeclareCiteCommand{\ccite}` or whatever you want.

Comment: @samcarter I know. Just wanted to mention it. This works great!