# Cite command similar to cleveref

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing, back-referencing

I would like a command which does with cited BibTex entries exactly what the package [`cleveref`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) does with equations and figures (via the command `\cref`).

This precise question was asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362221/clever-cite-command) a few years ago, but it only got one answer which works just for Biblatex and is incompatible with BibTex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive approach for BibTeX using `\IfSubStr` from the `xstring` package to check if the argument contains a comma, and print *ref* or *refs* accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\ccite}[1]{%
\IfSubStr{#1}{,}{refs.~}{ref.~}\cite{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\Ccite}[1]{%
\IfSubStr{#1}{,}{Refs.~}{Ref.~}\cite{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
See \ccite{manual-full} and \ccite{inbook-minimal,incollection-minimal}.
\Ccite{manual-full} is interesting. \Ccite{inbook-minimal,incollection-minimal} not so much.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A variant of [Marijn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628205/4427) without packages: we check whether the argument is a clist (comma separated list) of length greater than 1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ccite}{m}
 {
  \dv_ccite:nn { r } { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\Ccite}{m}
 {
  \dv_ccite:nn { R } { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \dv_ccite:nn
 {
  #1ef % #1 is either r or R
  \int_compare:nT { \clist_count:n { #2 } > 1 } { s } % if more than one, print s
  .\nobreakspace
  \cite{#2}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

See \ccite{manual-full} and \ccite{inbook-minimal,incollection-minimal}.
\Ccite{manual-full} is interesting. \Ccite{inbook-minimal,incollection-minimal} not so much.

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I've never seen citation marks preceded by “ref.”.